# Homebrew macOS - Python installation

Tags: python, macos, homebrew

I've installed python via homebrew. It is located in:
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13_1
which should be right.
Now I am trying to use this python installation, but "which python" only shows the macOS python installation at "/usr/bin/python". So i am checking the $PATH and I see that everything should be ok.

"echo $PATH" results in this: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

I restarted the terminal window and this occurs every time. I also did the
"brew doctor" and no warnings appeared.

What I am using:
Standard macOS Terminal-App

Has anybody a clue how this problem could be solved?

Comment: Try to add python bin dir of homebrew to PATH: "export PATH=`brew --prefix python`/bin:$PATH

Answer (score 0):

Update `$PATH` in your `.bashrc` file.

Example add the following line in your `.bashrc`

`export PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13_1/bin:$PATH`

Answer (score 0):

Either add the Python Homebrew prefix to your `$PATH`, like @Zico suggests in his answer, or link the Python executable into `/usr/local/bin` (which might already be in your path)

You'd do that with

```
$ brew link python
```

Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Brew create an python2 alias to

```
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
```

I just created a copy of python2 alias and rename it to python. That solved the problem